# Bootstrap modal 3 check if button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a project with fullcalendar and bootstrap v3 (newest)

I want to use a modalbox bootstrap styled. I want to define my own buttons in the jQuery because that way I can keep all data inside the fullcalender functions.

Part of js

```
select:  function(start, end, allDay) { 
            $('#selectModal').on('#Create', function (e) {
              // do something...
            })
        },
```

Bootstrap modal

```
<!-- Modal box for select -->
<div class="modal fade" id="selectModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="selectModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Medewerker</label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="selectBoxMedewerker">          
                        <?php foreach($this->users as $user):?>
                            <option  id="<?=$user->webuserId;?>" value="<?=$user->firstName;?> <?=$user->preposition;?> <?=$user->lastName;?>"><?=$user->firstName;?> <?=$user->preposition;?> <?=$user->lastName;?></option>
                        <?php endforeach;?>
                    </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" id="description" class="form-control" placeholder="Description">
            </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" id="Create" class="btn btn-primary">Create</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

**The Problem**

If I strip out

```
$('#selectModal').on('#Create', function (e) {
              // do something...
            })
```

Everything works fine but when I add it (to check if create is clicked) I get this error in firebug:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id
$('#Create').click(function(){});
```

What am I doing wrong here ^

**Updated Code:**

```
select:  function(start, end, allDay) {
            $('#selectModal').modal({
                $('#selectModal').on('click','#Create', function (e) {alert('something')});
            });
        },
```

**Working Code**

```
    $('#selectModal').modal({

    });
    $('#selectModal').on('click','#Create', function (e) {alert('something')});
```

There is still something wrong with the 'updated code'. I put the check on Create click out the modal and it works.

So my goal is reached. Thanks!

Comment: need an event declaration in the `.on()` call (e.g. `.on('click','#Create',function(){ ... })`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax for <kbd>[on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)</kbd> is `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler(eventObject) )` where `events` is mandatory. Hence specify `click` event

```
$('#selectModal').on('click','#Create', function (e) {
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try replacing:

`$('#Create').click(function(){});`

With:

```
$('#Create').on('click',function(){

});
```

Your current statement is being interpreted as an object literal.

Comment: trying it out and editing my post, I see I made mistake in the code I posted. Thanks!